# CUDA/C++ code profiling - hit time, function call statistic

Tags: c++, cuda, statistics, profiling

I have bunch of CUDA/C++ files from SDK examples. I would like to make statistics - to count which function calls occurs most frequently. For example. cudaFree or cudaMalloc probably will be on top. Anyway is there any good profiling tool or script to do that?

Comment: Any reason why you can not use Visual Studio Profiler? cudaFree and cudaMalloc are part of cuda runtime so you should not, I believe, need any special profiler for that...

Comment: I think he wants to make the statistics without compiling and running the code.

Comment: Well then perform full text search over files of interest and count occurences of function calls :) Total commander should do the trick...